# Case in where clause gives syntax error in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am working on reporting side, when start date and end date is selected the report should display the data between the date range, if  dates are not selected then the report should display all records present in the table.

The below SQL gives syntax error at 1=1:

```
select  a.PURCH_DOC_DATE from PURCH_SCHED_LINE_FACT a 
 where  
 (case when a.CLIENT_ID='0050' then a.PURCH_DOC_DATE 
       when a.CLIENT_ID='0057' then a.STATS_DELIV_DATE
       else 1=1
end)
between  '01-01-2014' and '12.12.2014'
```

Comment: Could you provide more about the error you are getting?

Comment: `CASE` is an *expression* that returns exactly one value of the highest data type precedence. You can't use it for flow control or to just dump out to `ELSE 1=1`. [Please read](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`case` does not work like this. Try instead

```
select  a.PURCH_DOC_DATE from PURCH_SCHED_LINE_FACT a 
where (a.CLIENT_ID='0050' and a.PURCH_DOC_DATE between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-12')
   or (a.CLIENT_ID='0057' and a.STATS_DELIV_DATE between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-12')
   or a.CLIENT_ID not in ('0050','0057')
```

Comment: I would recommend using parentheses to separate the different sets of related predicates when mixing `AND` and `OR`. It may be clear to you how operator precedence works here, but probably is not to 95+% of your readers...